# Crosstalk filter list of plotly to build conditional subplot

Tags: r, plotly, crosstalk

I am trying to filter a named list of `plotly` objects dynamicaly in `R`.

Goal is to display a subset of them inside a subplot according to a datetime range from user. Code has to be runned from a **rmarkdown** html document or in interactive mode from **RStudio**.

Current code:

```
library(crosstalk)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)

size <- 5

df <- data.frame(plotly = character(size))
df$plotly <- lapply(1:size, function(x) {
  plotly::plot_ly(x = x, y = x, type = "bar")
})
df$date <- as.Date(Sys.Date() - 1:size)
df

shared_plotly_list <- SharedData$new(df, key = ~date)

crosstalk::bscols(
  widths = 12,
  list(
    filter_slider("slider_id_plotly", "Label", shared_plotly_list, ~date),
    plotly::subplot(shared_plotly_list$data()$plotly, shareX = TRUE, nrows = length(shared_plotly_list$data()$plotly))
  )
)
```

Output shows all wanted plots without applying any filter. Changing slider values does not update output subplot yet.

Thanks, any help sincerely appreciated.

Comment: The date information has nothing to do with the data plotted. When you created the plots you didn't use the dates. When you added the dates, the plots were already created and when you called `subplot` you called `df$plotly` - thus excluding the dates. What did you expect would happen?

Comment: Everything is normal. Date 1 corresponds to display plot 1.The filter is suppose to happen later in the UI with the link object `shared_plotly_list`